# How does operating system knows execution time of process

Tags: operating-system

I was revisiting Operating Systems CPU job scheduling and suddenly a question popped in my mind, How the hell the OS knows the execution time of process before its execution, I mean in the scheduling algorithms like SJF(shortest job first), how the execution time of process is calculated apriori ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Wikipedia:

`Another disadvantage of using shortest job next is that the total execution time of a job must be known before execution. While it is not possible to perfectly predict execution time, several methods can be used to estimate the execution time for a job, such as a weighted average of previous execution times.[1]`

More on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_job_next

Comment: oops my bad, I forgot to check wiki page. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Also, O.S can compute the total needed time for each task, by means of first calculating its CPI.

**(CPI: cycles per instruction)**

There is a weighted average CPI for each job. 
For example, floating point instructions weigh much more than fixed point instructions, meaning they take more time to perform. So a job dealing with fixed point operations: like add or increment is perceived to be shorter. Hence in a shortest job first, it shall be executed prior to the aforementioned job.